# Getting Ldap error while committing bulk group member changes

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I am trying to execute the following code for making bulk changes (adding/deleting 100K members) to LDAP group:

```
using (DirectoryEntry Connection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + currentGroupDN))
{
    foreach (DataRow row in action.Rows)
    {
        var dn = row["dn"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dn))
        {
            if (row["Action"].ToString().ToUpper() == "ADD")
            {
                Connection.Properties["member"].Add(dn);
            }
            else if (row["Action"].ToString().ToUpper() == "REMOVE")
            {
                Connection.Properties["member"].Remove(dn);
            }
        }
    }
    Connection.CommitChanges();
}
```

But the code fails while committing changes with folowing error:
The server is unwilling to process the request.
**Error message: 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D50, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v2580**

Comment: I assume that there is some limitation in ldap with number of values being added. Commit every 1000 rows, not the entire membership. This should resolve the issue

Comment: @oldovets, I can certainly do that but I wanted to make sure all my changes are in sync with LDAP. Either none or all members should be updated during a single execution cycle. I am just not sure why LDAP does not like committing bulk changes. Anyways, thanks for your reply.